# How to convert polygon into hexagonal grid?

Tags: qgis, mmqgis, hexagon-binning, hexagonal-grid

I'm trying to convert a polygon shapefile of the UK into a hex grid. Using MMQGIS I've produced the grid, then I tried the intersect tool which gave me something close to what I want. However, the irregular edge of the UK borders has cut some of the hexagons. Is there a way of keeping all of the hexagons whole and producing an 'approximation' of the original polygon.

Answer (score 4):

You actually want a `selection` of the grid rather than a geometric modification of it so use `Select by Location` (one menu lower down under `Vector Selection Tools`) and chose intersects and contains to pick up all the hexagons that are within and overlapped by the UK polygons. Then you'll need to save the selection to a new file of course.